# Remote Desktop into the current auto-logged-in user

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, auto-login

I have a windows machine acting as a server for a few different things. In order to have windows run what I need on startup, I set a user to autologin and start the programs I need. This works fine except for when I need to Remote Desktop into the session. Whenever I try to remote desktop to the current user session (the user that was auto logged in), I see the screen for half a second and then get the error "you have been disconnected because another connection was made to the remote pc"

Does anyone know why this is happening? From researching online, all I could find was an option to allow multiple simultaneous remote sessions, but this doesn't make any sense as I'm only connecting with a single remote session. I'm just trying to remote desktop to the user that's logged in.

Comment: “Does anyone know why this is happening?” - You are attempting to use a consumer edition of Windows as a server instead of using an appropriate licensed edition of Windows Server. Furthermore, you cannot log into the same user twice,

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Professional, is that still considered a "consumer-edition"?

Comment: This also is not an adequate explanation for the error message, since the error message is not "you are using a consumer edition of Windows", and I also mention that I am not logging onto the same user twice. The question clearly states my use-case

Comment: I am not a huge fan of VNC but it might help you here.

Comment: VNC creates a new session and doesn't connect to the existing session as far as I'm aware

Comment: @lufinkey - Yes, of course it is, because it’s not an edition that requires a KMS. You indicated, “Whenever I try to remote desktop to the current user session”, that sounds like you’re logging into the same user.  Once automatically, second remotely.

Comment: Right. The question is asking how to control the current user session, but I've already left the correct answer, so this is indeed something that's possible

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out, but it's a bit weird and requires a second user.

1. Log in as a different user from the one that's currently logged in. Select "Yes" to the prompt of disconnecting the existing user (it just locks their session but doesn't actually log them out).
2. Open Task Manager, Select "Users", find the user session for the current desktop session, right click, and select "Connect". Then you will have control over the current desktop session.

NOTE: This still seems to randomly disconnect you with the same error message sometimes, but it happens every 3 minutes or so